# Web Scraping Selenium and Beautiful soup - unable to export into csv file

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, export-csv

I am trying to web scrape the data (price + brand) from this website. The code actually works but I can only see the data on my sublime text editor and cannot convert it into a CSV file. Additionally, I get this error message:

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'div'
```

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd

PATH = "/Users/Ziye/Desktop/Python/chromedriver"

def get_html(url):
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
    driver.get(url)
    return driver.page_source

def main ():
    rows = []
    url = "https://www.yoox.com/de/damen/kleidung/shoponline/michael%20kors_md#/Md=403&d=10321&dept=clothingwomen&gender=D&page=2&season=X"
    html = get_html(url)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "lxml")
    cards = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "col-8-24"})
    print(len(cards))


    for card in cards:
        print(card.find(class_="itemData text-center").div.get_text())

        print(card.find(class_="price").get_text())
    
        row = {'Brand': card.find(class_="brand font-bold text-uppercase").get_text(),
               'Price': card.find(class_="price").get_text()}
    
        rows.append(row)
    
    df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
    df.to_csv('file.csv', index=False)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get items from second page, replace `#` in URL for `?`:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.yoox.com/de/damen/kleidung/shoponline/michael%20kors_md?/Md=403&d=10321&dept=clothingwomen&gender=D&page=2&season=X"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

data = []
for item in soup.select(".itemlink"):
    data.append(
        {
            "Brand": item.select_one(".brand").get_text(strip=True),
            "Category": item.select_one(".microcategory").get_text(strip=True),
            "Price": item.select_one(".fullprice, .newprice").get_text(
                strip=True
            ),
        }
    )


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                    Brand                      Category       Price
0    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS               Knielange Röcke   EUR 99,00
1    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider  EUR 188,00
2    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Pullover  EUR 180,00
3    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 184,00
4    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Oversize-T-Shirts   EUR 75,00
5    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider  EUR 235,00
6    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                    Midi-Röcke  EUR 156,00
7    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 76,00
8    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Leggings  EUR 154,00
9    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Looks für zuhause   EUR 85,00
10   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                   Steppjacken  EUR 400,00
11   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Overalls  EUR 180,00
12   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS            Rollkragenpullover  EUR 131,00
13   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider  EUR 141,00
14   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS   Hemden und Blusen einfarbig  EUR 132,00
15   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 212,00
16   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 124,00
17   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 95,00
18   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 119,00
19   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 62,00
20   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                   Bikerjacken  EUR 550,00
21   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 139,00
22   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider   EUR 83,00
23   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Looks für zuhause   EUR 75,00
24   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 99,00
25   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS   Hemden und Blusen aus Seide  EUR 109,00
26   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 145,00
27   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                  Lange Jacken  EUR 226,00
28   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 66,00
29   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 43,00
30   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider   EUR 66,00
31   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS              Kaschmirpullover  EUR 273,00
32   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                        Blusen   EUR 74,00
33   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider   EUR 64,00
34   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS  Hemden und Blusen mit Blumen   EUR 99,00
35   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                   Steppjacken  EUR 247,00
36   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                  Bomberjacken  EUR 325,00
37   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Looks für zuhause   EUR 95,00
38   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Knielange Kleider  EUR 347,00
39   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Pullover  EUR 195,00
40   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen  EUR 264,00
41   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                       Bikinis   EUR 99,00
42   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                   Sweatshirts  EUR 150,00
43   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Knielange Kleider  EUR 192,00
44   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 74,00
45   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS  Hemden und Blusen aus Spitze  EUR 118,00
46   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                  Lange Jacken  EUR 225,00
47   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                   Sweatshirts   EUR 94,00
48   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Overalls  EUR 235,00
49   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 134,00
50   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 59,00
51   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 79,00
52   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                    Midi-Röcke  EUR 109,00
53   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 90,00
54   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                   Steppjacken  EUR 225,00
55   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen  EUR 234,00
56   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 104,00
57   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Overalls  EUR 129,00
58   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
59   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS      Cropped-Hosen & Culottes   EUR 99,00
60   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 84,00
61   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
62   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
63   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS   Hemden und Blusen aus Seide  EUR 250,00
64   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
65   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Jacketts  EUR 194,00
66   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
67   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                    Midi-Röcke   EUR 99,00
68   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Overalls  EUR 235,00
69   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS       Cabanjacke & Zweireiher  EUR 525,00
70   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider   EUR 67,00
71   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                     Miniröcke  EUR 150,00
72   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                        Mäntel  EUR 395,00
73   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen  EUR 175,00
74   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 124,00
75   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS  Hemden und Blusen mit Muster   EUR 94,00
76   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen   EUR 94,00
77   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                  Midi-Kleider  EUR 225,00
78   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 138,00
79   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 450,00
80   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS            Rollkragenpullover  EUR 135,00
81   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Pullover  EUR 195,00
82   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                    Midi-Röcke  EUR 109,00
83   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider  EUR 168,00
84   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Shorts & Bermudas   EUR 84,00
85   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                  Strickjacken   EUR 99,00
86   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
87   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 131,00
88   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 144,00
89   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 89,00
90   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen  EUR 124,00
91   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                    Midi-Röcke   EUR 99,00
92   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
93   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Pullover  EUR 249,00
94   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 109,00
95   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS            Rollkragenpullover  EUR 119,00
96   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
97   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 86,00
98   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Hemdchen  EUR 109,00
99   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 109,00
100  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 309,00
101  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                  Midi-Kleider  EUR 175,00
102  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                        Blusen   EUR 84,00
103  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen  EUR 139,00
104  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 110,00
105  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen  EUR 124,00
106  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 94,00
107  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS     Gerade geschnittene Hosen  EUR 129,00
108  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 149,00
109  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS            Schulterfreies Top   EUR 79,00
110  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                        Blusen  EUR 250,00
111  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                        Blusen  EUR 225,00
112  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 150,00
113  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider  EUR 159,00
114  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Jacketts  EUR 210,00
115  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen   EUR 79,00
116  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                        Blusen  EUR 103,00
117  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                         Hosen  EUR 111,00
118  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Jacketts  EUR 154,00
119  MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider  EUR 144,00
```

And creates `data.csv` (screenshot from LibreOffice):

[image]

---

EDIT: To get oldprice, newprice and fullprice into separate columns:

```
import requests
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = "https://www.yoox.com/de/damen/kleidung/shoponline/michael%20kors_md?/Md=403&d=10321&dept=clothingwomen&gender=D&page=2&season=X"
soup = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).content, "lxml")

data = []
for item in soup.select(".itemlink"):
    data.append(
        {
            "Brand": item.select_one(".brand").get_text(strip=True),
            "Category": item.select_one(".microcategory").get_text(strip=True),
            "Old Price": item.select_one(".oldprice").get_text(strip=False)
            if item.select_one(".oldprice")
            else "",
            "New Price": item.select_one(".newprice").get_text(strip=False)
            if item.select_one(".newprice")
            else "",
            "Full Price": item.select_one(".fullprice").get_text(strip=False)
            if item.select_one(".fullprice")
            else "",
        }
    )


df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)
df.to_csv("data.csv", index=False)
```

Prints:

```
                    Brand                      Category   Old Price   New Price  Full Price
0    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS               Knielange Röcke                           EUR 99,00
1    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider  EUR 235,00  EUR 188,00            
2    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Pullover  EUR 225,00  EUR 180,00            
3    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Kurze Kleider                          EUR 184,00
4    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Oversize-T-Shirts                           EUR 75,00
5    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                 Lange Kleider                          EUR 235,00
6    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                    Midi-Röcke  EUR 195,00  EUR 156,00            
7    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      T-Shirts   EUR 95,00   EUR 76,00            
8    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Leggings  EUR 175,00  EUR 154,00            
9    MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS             Looks für zuhause                           EUR 85,00
10   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                   Steppjacken  EUR 450,00  EUR 400,00            
11   MICHAEL MICHAEL KORS                      Overalls  EUR 225,00  EUR 180,00            

...
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This works beautifully. Just one last question: could you maybe tell me how to add an extra column into the csv file for the full price of the products?

Comment: I somehow get an SyntaxError in line 16, it says:
if (i:= item.select_one(".oldprice"))
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @ZiYe You're using old version of Python3. I advise to upgrade. I've updated my answer.